# Any way to fetch hyperlink of a column to another column on google spreadsheet?

Tags: hyperlink, spreadsheet, google-docs

I copy a list of company name from a website, each of them has its hyperlink.

But now I would like to paste the names on column B of a google spreadsheet and the link list on column C.

[the sample spreadsheet shows here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3IE6.png)

Column B shows name and column C shows its link like http://.....

The =HYPERLINK function syntax are as followed

HYPERLINK(url, [link_label])

Is there any way I can make the [link_label] become link url itself?

Or is there any other way to list all the hyperlink of a sheet on a column?

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets in a Google function indicate that the parameter is optional. HYPERLINK defaults to display the link itself if the [link_label] is omitted.

In other words, =HYPERLINK("www.example.com") will display as [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

[See Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en).